# Minimum of floating-point numbers

Tags: binary, machine-precision

I'm reading the book Numerical Analysis by Gautschi, and in the first chapter the author makes the following assertion:

The set of floating-point numbers on a computer is denoted $\mathbb R(t,s)$ such that:
$$
x \in \mathbb R(t,s) \iff x = f \cdot 2^e
$$
where,
$f = \pm (.b_{-1}\cdots b_{-t})_2$ and $e = \pm (c_{s-1}\cdots c_0.)_2.$ Here every
$b_i$ and $c_j$ are binarary digits.

Then, the author states that a number $x$ is said to be *normalized* if in its fraction $f$ we have $b_{-1}=1$.

Finally, he claims that from this definition, we can easily see that for the normalized numbers we have
$$
\min_{x \in \mathbb R(t,s)}|x| = 2^{-2^s}.
$$

I don't follow why the minimum is given by the formula above. If I understood correctly, the minimum should be $1/2 \cdot 2^{-2^s}$, since the minimum of $f$ is $1/2$.

Can anyone explain why the minimum is the one given by the author
?

Comment: $\dfrac 1 2 $ is $2^{-1}$ and the least exponent is $2^{s-1}$

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Wouldn't it be $2 ^{-2^s - 1}$?

Comment: Try simple test cases. With $s=1$ we have only $c_0$ that has only two possible values: $0$ and $1$. Thus, the least number will be $\dfrac 1 2 \cdot 2^{-1}=2^{-1} \cdot 2^{-1}=2^{-2}=2^{-2^1}$.

Comment: Try now to compute it with $s=2$. We will have that the least exponent will be $-3$ and thus $\dfrac 1 2 \cdot 2^{-3}=2^{-4}=2^{-2^2}$.

Comment: As you can see, the little exponent is equal to $s$.

Comment: Thanks! I understood.